# JQuery: Animated resize of div after loading content which ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I use the following code to reload the content of the div #console every second.

```
var update = setInterval(
    function(){
        $("#console").load("/console");
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    }, 1000
);
```

This works quite well. Additionally I would like, that the resizement of the div is animated.

I tried something like this:

```
            $("#console").load("/console").animate({height: 'auto'}, 1000);
```

But it doesnt work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for your answers, that worked!
But there is still another problem I did not see:

I call

```
animate({height: 'auto'}, 1000)
```

but animate just can deal with numerical values but now with 'auto'.
I intended, that the div always fits to the content. Can that be realized somehow?

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce ? Most likely you are trying to resize before the content is loaded

Comment: have you tried  `$("#console").load("/console", function(){
                         $(this).animate({height: 'auto'}, 1000);
                        });`

Comment: `.animate()` requires a numeric value for the CSS element being animated.  Try your code with a number of pixels or percent instead of 'auto' and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
var update = setInterval(
            function () {
                $("#console").load("/console", function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if (textStatus == "success") {
                        $("#console").animate({ height: 'auto' }, 1000);
                    }
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            }, 1000
        );
```

Comment: Yeah, using the handler of `load` instead of chaining the `animate` should do the trick